# Creating multipatch layer in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.0, editing

I would like to create a multipatch layer in ArcMap using the editor tool.

I have looked online but couldn't find any tutorials or help.

How can I create a multipatch layer in ArcMap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use [SketchUp](http://www.sketchup.com/) (used to be Google SketchUp).

You can do a lot with the free basic version.

Follow instructions at [ArcGIS to SketchUp and back](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/10/25/arcgis-to-sketchup-and-back/) to convert from SketchUp to ArcGIS multipatch.